# Obtain form value from Drupal 6 module form while loop

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-forms

inside form hook:

```
     $count = 1;
    while($slice = db_fetch_array($fruit)){
      $section = $slice['section'];

      $form[$section][$count] = array(
          '#type' => $slice['type'],
          '#title' => $slice['title'],
      '#value' =>$slice['value'],
        //'#default_value' => $slice['default_value'],
      '#disabled' => $true_statement,
          '#size' => $slice['size'],
      '#description' => $slice['description'], 
      '#options' => unserialize($slice['options']), 
      '#prefix' => $slice['prefix'], 
      '#suffix' => $slice['suffix'], 
);
    $count = $count+1;
    }
```

inside save :

```
function student_grant_save($form, &$form_state) {
  $vari = $form_state['values']['2'];  //or question count # 3,4,5...etc...
  drupal_set_message(t('hi').$vari);
}
```

only the hi gets printed. Why can't i see the form value that the user imputed?
i used dpm($form_state);   and I see that i have value entries but they are blank even though user entered them in. 
 For some reason the 'value' entry in my mysql table that has all the question atributes, is taking over the 'default_value' and not letting the user alter the form values upon submit. Is there any way around this?

Comment: Check what you getting in $form_state using `dpm($form_state)`.

Comment: So hope you get it solved now.

Comment: no, that would not be the case... i knew about dpm, but the problem has to do with setting the 'values'

Comment: try print_r($form_state['values']); exit; and check what values you get

Comment: Enable the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module and use the dsm() function to highlight the array you need to pull from.  It's way easier than print_r()

Comment: Can you paste the entire `hook_form`?

Comment: Thanks. I must have figured out the solution. I'll edit this later with the answer. Cheers!